# javafx - can't see textfield

Tags: java, javafx-8, textfield

I'm working on a paint like app for a school project, and I want to be able to press the text box button and then wherever you click a text box appears to interact with. However, i am not able to accomplish this right now. The text field is being created i believe but it is not visible and I am unable to type in any text.

Here is my mouse pressed event handler for when the text box option is selected.

Thanks

```
/ MOUSE_PRESSED event handler for rootLayout
    rootLayout.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    mode = controller.getMode();
                    oldX = event.getX();
                    oldY = event.getY();
                    switch(mode){
                        case 2:
                            System.out.print("created text field");
                            TextField textfield = new TextField();
                            textfield.setLayoutX(oldX);
                            textfield.setLayoutY(oldY);
                            textfield.setPrefSize(100, 100);

                            rootLayout.getChildren().add(textfield);
                            break;
                }
                }
            });
```

Comment: There's nothing at all wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: Interesting, maybe it's in another part, because as I said it doesn't work properly.